# Why is this regex not removing '\' and '-'?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove backslashes and hyphens from text using a regular expression to match for characters to remove.

```
SPL_CHAR2 = r"[,(.;)@\#?\|!-+_*=~<>/&$]+"

def remove_special_chars(text: str) -> str:
    text = re.sub(SPL_CHAR2, ' ', text)
    return text
```

The issue is that these characters are not being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters have special meaning in the regex definition.  To make this work, rearrange the character set like so:

```
SPL_CHAR2 = r"[-,(.;)@\#?\\|!+_*=~<>/&$]+"
```

I've moved the dash to the start (so that it's no longer defining a *character range*) and have doubled the backslash.

Instead of moving the dash to the start, you can keep it where it is but add a backslash right before it.

The syntax is defined here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax (search for `[]`).